# Help needed with reading data from server in java

Tags: java, byte, bytebuffer

i am having a bit of trouble with DataInputStreams,

So i have data coming for a local server, i know that the bytes i read in will follow this format

0x01 to specify it is a string

then random amount of bytes

followed by trailing 0x00 0x00,

i am having trouble reading from the server though,

here is my method for reading

```
    public static String convertFromServer(DataInputStream dis) throws IOException{
    //Buffer to hold bytes being read in
    ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    if(dis.read() != -1){
        //Check to see if first byte == 0x01
    if(dis.read() == 0x01){
        //Check if byte dosnt equal 0x00, i need it to check if it is actually 0x00 0x00
        while(dis.read() != 0x00){
            buf.write(dis.read());
        }
    }

    if(dis.read() == 0x03){    

        while(dis.read() != 0x00){

            buf.write(dis.read());
        }
    }
    }
    String messageRecevied = new String(buf.toByteArray());
    return messageRecevied;

}
```

If i am a little ambiguous let me know.

i am getting data back , its just not fully correct, basically what i do is send across a byte array, with with the first element being 0x01 to specify string, then the string in bytes and then finally the last 2 elements are 0x00 and 0x00, then this data is then sent back to me from the server, the server definitely receives the data, just when i am reading back it not correct, letter will be missing

this code writes encodes the data i nthe format 0x01, then message in bytes, then 0x00,0x00

```
  public static void writeStringToBuffer(ByteArrayOutputStream buf,String message){

    buf.write(0x01);

    byte[] b = message.getBytes();

    for(int i =1; i<message.getBytes().length+1;i++ ){

        buf.write(b[i-1]);

     }
    buf.write(0x00);
    buf.write(0x00);


}
```

Comment: Well, you're only checking for one 0 (but you alraedy know that), and there could also be an econding issue behind it. Can you show us the code that is writing the data into the stream?

Comment: i updated the question with how i encode the message , i then use dataOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()) to send it across, the data is received and displayed correctly server side with the 0x01 ,0x00,0x00 removed and then converted to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that always gets me when I'm doing socket work is making sure the orders are reversed on the server and the client.

If the server reads first, the client has to write first. If the Server writes first, the client has to read first. If they're both trying to read or both trying to write, you won't get any output.

My recommendation is to do this:

```
if(dis.read() == 0x01) {
    int zeroesInARow = 0;

    while(zeroesInARow < 2) {
        int b = dis.read()
        if(b == 0x00) zeroesInARow++;
        else zeroesInARow = 0;
        buf.write(b);
    }
    String rawMessage = new String(buf.toArray());
    // take off the last two 0s
    String messageRecevied = rawMessage.substring(0,rawMessage.length()-2);
    return messageRecevied;
}
```

Comment: i am getting data back , its just not fully correct, basically what i do is send across a byte array, with with the first element being 0x01 to specify string, then the string in bytes and then finally the last 2 elements are 0x00 and 0x00, then this data is then sent back to me from the server, the server definitely receives the data, just when i am reading back it not correct, letter will be missing

Comment: also i have no access to the server code, all i know is it will send back the data i sent it

Comment: server side can only interpret TYPE MESSAGE END_FLAG

Comment: updated with parsing as per spec. I don't like it, i think it's kind of ugly, but if you can't control the format of the input, that's how I'd do it.

Comment: It's worth noting that you could just always send string messages by default, and that if you need to send some binary data, make a message that says "the next line is binary data with format ___"

Comment: well binary data is specified by 0x03

Comment: thank you very much, this has worked , but only for a string , no im trying to do the same thing, but for binary data

Comment: Well, you can't change the server anyway. Although in both cases you're writing everything to a string... soooo...

Comment: Well I'm willing to help you out there too. What format is the binary data? Is it going to be ints? shorts? longs? floats?

Comment: dude, just got a little stuck, when i am encoding my data, and lets say it looks like this , 0x03,randomdata 0x0x (apart of bin data), finnally 0x,0x(endFlag). would look like this 0x03,0x05,0x07,0x06,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00 , how would i go about encoding it so it would look like this 0x03,0x05,0x07,0x06,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00 just to specify that the first two zeros are apart of the bin data and not the end flag

Comment: There's nothing you can do to get around that. That's why I recommended TYPE LENGTH MESSAGE encoding to prevent that from happening. :-)

Comment: there has to be away around it, Null terminated encodings would not work if there wasnt